# Define variables for all hosts in Ansible dynamic inventory

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to define host variables for all hosts using a dynamic inventory?

Currently I can produce an inventory which allows me to assign variables to specific hosts, but what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "all": {
                "my_global_random_variable": "global_random_value"
            }
        }
    },
    "web_servers": {
        "children": [],
        "hosts": [
            "web_server1",
            "web_server2"
        ],
        "vars": {}
    },
    "database_servers": {
        "children": [],
        "hosts": [
            "database_server1"
        ],
        "vars": {}
    }
}
```

Which should allow me to access the "my_global_random_variable" from any context as if I would have defined that variable in a vars file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a lookup plugin instead of the inventory to retrieve my variables.

More information on lookups: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html

Answer (score 1):

Variables set by `dynamic inventory` are `inventory variables`. When a variable is set in multiple places Ansible set the value following [variable precedence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable):

> ```
>   role defaults [1]
>     inventory vars [2]
>     inventory group_vars
>     inventory host_vars
>     playbook group_vars
>     playbook host_vars
>     host facts
>     play vars
>     play vars_prompt
>     play vars_files
>     registered vars
>     set_facts
>     role and include vars
>     block vars (only for tasks in block)
>     task vars (only for the task)
>     extra vars (always win precedence)
> ```

Variables set in inventory have a relativ low precendence. So there is no need to use `dynamic inventory` to achive this. Just set the variable for example on role level.

Comment: This wouldn't have helped me because I had a dynamic inventory which retrieved data from LDAP.

Comment: I ended up using a lookup plugin which seems to be the right way.
Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this and seems to work with the following (adapted for your example):

```
{
    "all": {
        "vars": {
            "my_global_random_variable": "global_random_value"
        }
    },
    "web_servers": {
        "children": [],
        "hosts": [
            "web_server1",
            "web_server2"
        ],
        "vars": {}
    },
    "database_servers": {
        "children": [],
        "hosts": [
            "database_server1"
        ],
        "vars": {}
    }
}
```

Possibly not best practice but keeps things simple.